# Powerquery SQL search for specific characters

Tags: sql, powerquery, m

```
DR_code  DR_lastname  DR_markers  
ACE      Acerine      H,h,J,D,L,K   
MER      Merger       P,L,M,n,D  
SMI      Smith        D,K,M,b,v  
SMI1     Smith        L,K,M,H,f
```

Within the above SQL-table I would like to search for clients that match specific markers. These markers can be put in by the user eg D & K. The search has to be case sensitive.

```
sql="SELECT DR_LASTNAME WHERE DR_MARKER COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN LIKE '%D%' AND DR_MARKER COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN LIKE '%K%'"
```

The above works but I would like the user to be able to select a custom number of markers.

I have the selected markers in a variable in Powerquery eg VAR_MARKERS = "DK" but I can't get this to work:

```
VAR_MARKERS="DK",    
sql="SELECT DR_LASTNAME WHERE DR_MARKER CONTAINS".VAR_MARKERS.""
```

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Fix your data model!  Don't store multiple values in a single string column.  That is not correct in any database.

Comment: Or use JSON for the `DR_markers` column, and corresponding functions to search in it.

Answer (score 0):

Does your database support regular expression? If so, then replace "&" with "|" (pipe) and use some function/predicate like "regexp_like".
[SQL Server example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=95dc4298c8b92a39421e62f614ff4af5). [Oracle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d5ba4127777d1c83da4d7e7c470371a4). [Postgres example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f6eef45b0374288881c580675f54358c).